# Microsoft Flow Doesn't Trigger Immediately?

Tags: power-automate

My Flow:

> Microsoft Form --> Capture Request Submit Timestamp --> Approval -->
>   Capture Approval Timestamp --> Send Email --> Store in DB

I've seen couple of posts mentioning that the flow doesn't trigger when the response is submitted. Sometimes the flow even skipped execution for some of my responses. Can anyone tell me how to configure flow to execute for every response submitted? The delay in triggering this flow is giving me inaccurate "Request Submit Timestamp". Also, I am not sure how to manually run this flow if execution is failed for any response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how Flow works. Some triggers polls your application periodically like every 5 minute or so.

And sometimes there is even more delay which might be caused on Microsofts side. I've experienced flows triggering several hours after an item was changed or submitted in our Sharepoint site.

If you visit [Microsoft Flow Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community/ct-p/FlowCommunity) and search that you'll se you're not alone in this. There might be an workaround posted there aswell that  fit your particular situation. It seems many users are experiencing similar difficulties.

Comment: Do you believe this is still the case? I'm debugging some flows and Microsoft's marketing of this tool makes it seem like an enterprise solution (ie reliable) and so far it seems really buggy and inconsistent.